Rotating an archimedean spiral
I'm trying to rotate an archimedean spiral in such a way that allows it to attach to another archimedean spiral without overlapping each other,  kind of like the image here below:

I've already figured out how to get each spiral to their corresponding 4 sides of the bigger spiral, but I don't know how to rotate them in such a way that has each spiral look like they are stemming from the main big spiral. Inversing the x and y axises of the spirals don't seem to help in this regard, and that's basically the only way I know how to rotate shapes.
A visual version of what I've achieved so far can be found here, but I'll also explain in text)what I know so far:

Archimedean spiral's equation is $r=a+(b*\theta)$, with...

$a$ controlling where the middlemost part of the spiral starts on the x axis
$b$ controlling the gap between the revolutions on the spiral

Specifically, B is a coefficient being multiplied by $\pi$. The product of that is used to calculate the distance between each arm revolution


$\theta$ controlling when the Spiral stops... spiraling? Spinning? Don't know the proper terminology for it, but you get what I mean. Also, $\theta$ is usually depicted in terms of $\pi$.


The part that I've figured out was calculating where the 4 spirals should be if they were to be made, but I don't know how to actually rotate the spiral when they get there. You do not need to worry about how to move the spiral to the point--just how to rotate it in the way seen in the picture
And that's about everything I know! Feel free to ask me any questions if you have any, but I'm not sure how useful I'll be in the grand scheme of things


Are you asking for an equation to graph an Archimedean spiral with a centre other than the origin and different rotation?

Just the rotation part-- I've already figured out how to move the origin

You should explain your reasoning and what you've found so far, instead of just providing a link. How exactly do you move the origin?

The link should already explain what each part of the archimedean spiral does in the variables folder, and the 4 multicolored points around the spiral is just there for my reference on where I want to put each rotated archimedean spiral when I figure out how to do that . But I get what you mean about me just providing a link and expecting people to click it and instantly know what to do. I'll update the question with more information about archimedean spiral like the equation I'm using and such

As for your question, You can edit the "a" variable to move the origin left/right, but I have no clue about up and down. However, I already know how I'm going to get the spirals in the correct place-- I just have no clue how to properly rotate them so they don't intersect wight each other

@Numeral Ok, I just finished updating the post with more information. Take a look!

The shape graphed by altering the $a$ variable is not an Archimedean spiral, it contains a closed loop for large values of $a$.
This can be fixed by altering the range of $\theta$ in the spiral equation to allow some $\theta<0$.
In fact, your $a$ parameter is exactly what rotates the spiral in this case.
